# volume controls discrepancy in Ubuntu/KDE

Tags: volume-control

I'm not sure if this is an issue with Ubuntu or KDE, because I've only used KDE. I've noticed this with 20.04. I've noticed that the main KDE volume control has an issue where the volume percentage bar doesn't match the bands coming out of the speaker icon indicate that the volume is off:
[image]

In the state in this screenshot, the actual volume in my headphones is completely off (which the speaker icon bands correctly show), even though the bar shows roughly 20%. I've noticed this same issue with a lot of other applications, including volume controls in various browsers (Opera, Brave, etc.).

Is there a reason for this discrepancy or is it a bug?